# Import/Read Combobox List from Web site and use in C# Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, web

I wish to read the two Combobox lists from this site:
http://coinmill.com/

Then I wish to recreate that in C# 2010 Combobox.

Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. And what is the question?

Comment: I think it's "How to" :)

Comment: @KaeL: here we go :-) How to create a combobox? How to find the combobox entries in the site's HTML source code? How to imitate the combobox style as it's shown by the browser? How to make the yellow background? Which of them?

Comment: I wish to get the list from that Combobox - In other words, I have a Form with two Comboboxes. I want to "download" the list to fill up my comboboxes from the Coinmill site.

Comment: @Xantor: Maybe you can just create your own `datasource` for your combo boxes. Wouldn't it be nice?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download and parse the page at coinmill. Write an xpath expression or traverse the DOM to find the select tag you´re looking for in the HtmlAgilityPack document. Get the list of options, and load them into your list. 
Mind you: this code can (and probably will) break every time coinmill updates their website. Your xpath or dom traversing is basing itself on the current layout of that page, and it will change. You would be better off looking for a webservice that offers the data you are looking for.

Menno

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go with the service option :)